# Cannot get custom Git command to work correctly

Tags: git, batch-file, windows-10

According to various sources, it should be possible to add a custom Git command by scripting up the Git commands, adding it to the path and making it executable (N.B. not really applicable in the windows world but the sources assumed a *nix rig).

I have created a batch file and added it to the path. The only problem is, I have to type:

```
git-my-command
```

But it should (apparently) be possible to call the command like regular Git commands so:

```
git my-command
```

It is a small annoyance but it would be good to get it working. Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Comment: `git my-command` works for me when `git-my-command` is in `$PATH`, no problem. Just tested, I have a few my own small commands.

Comment: Can you show us what `where git-my-command` outputs in the context where you're running `git my-command`? Does `PATH` in that context include the containing directory?

Comment: There `where` command finds the script fine - otherwise git-my-command wouldn't work, so it doesn't seem to be an issue with the path.

Answer (score -1):

Git *should* automatically pick up on executables named `git-*` on your `PATH`. Make sure that you have execute permissions for `git-my-command`. If you're missing execute permissions, git will still just give the blanket `git: 'my-command' is not a git command.` error.

Failing that (say, if you can't control `PATH` in your specific usecase), you can create a [git alias](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) for your custom command:

```
git config --global alias.my-command '!/path/to/my-command'
```

Note the leading `!`, which is required to reference an external command instead of a git subcommand.

Then, invoking

```
git my-command x y z
```

will call `/path/to/my-command x y z`.